# Regex brings all lines. I want to make PS script to find all password pattern in File server

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to make powershell scripts for search all documents and txt files to find Password pattern. Actually my code is working fine. My regex is capture password but it brings all lines.

***Regex Pattern***

""" .*(?=.{8,20})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!^#+$%&{()=}?*-|¨@.,:;,]).* """

[Samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm5UN.png)
[Samples2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUn5V.png)

My regex bring all Line. How can fix this error.

***PS Code***

```
$Path = "c:\users\XXXXXXX"
$output_file = ‘C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Desktop\Result.txt’
$ALLWORDS =Get-ChildItem $Path  -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

foreach ($WORDS in $ALLWORDS) { #
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $false
$regex = ‘\b.*(?=.{8,20})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!^#+$%&{()=}?*\-|¨@.,:;,]).*\b’
$Doc = $Word.Documents.Open($WORDS.FullName, $false, $true)
$paras = $doc.Paragraphs
echo $paras.count
             
                    foreach($para in $paras){
                  if( $para.range.text -match $regex)  { 
                  $1=$matches.Values,$Words.Name | Out-File $output_file -Append
                  Write-Host $matches.Values, $words.Name 
                    }
                    }
                     
    $Doc.Close()
    $Word.Quit()
    $Word = $null
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your pattern supposed to catch? There is currently no anchor at the end, so with `.*` you capture 0+ characters. Besides, your pattern looks to be problematic since the positive lookaheads can't be correct for all these options on the 1st character. **EDIT** the pattern in the question is different to the one in your linked example.

Comment: at least  one digit
at least one lowercase Character.
at least one uppercase characterat least one special character. 
at minimum length 8 max 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<!\S)(?=[^a-z\s]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z\s]*[A-Z])(?=[^0-9\s]*[0-9])(?=\S*[!^#+$%&{()=}?*|¨@.,:;,-])\S{8,20}(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/myaBvg/1). **Note** you need to use `-cmatch` operator instead of `-match` in PowerShell, or it will be case insensitive.

*Details*:

- `(?<!\S)` - no whitespace on the left allowed
- `(?=[^a-z\s]*[a-z])` - after any zero or more chars other than whitespace and lowercase ASCII letters, there must be a lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?=[^A-Z\s]*[A-Z])` - after any zero or more chars other than whitespace and uppercase ASCII letters, there must be an uppercase ASCII letter
- `(?=[^0-9\s]*[0-9])` - after any zero or more chars other than whitespace and ASCII digits, there must be an ASCII digit
- `(?=\S*[!^#+$%&{()=}?*|¨@.,:;,-])` - after any zero or more non-whitespaces, there must be a symbol from `[!^#+$%&{()=}?*|¨@.,:;,-]` set (replace `\S*` with `[^\s!^#+$%&{()=}?*|¨@.,:;,-]*` for better performance, I just wanted to keep the pattern shorter here)
- `\S{8,20}` - eight to twenty non-whitespace chars
- `(?!\S)` - a right-hand whitespace boundary.

Comment: Is there anyway to change Regex  to re2(golang)? Positive lookahead does not support for golang .

Comment: @Tkoksal There is no way to convert this pattern to a RE2 pattern, you need to write your own parser.